# Jetpack Compose Image composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am solving a problem on layouts in jetpack compose and i am encountering an error that i don't understand what it is. I tried asking ChatGPT but it also did not solve it. The error is something confusing so i will be copy pasting my code and the screenshot of the error message I received.

I tried to try layout problems in jetpack compose so I tried to write some text over an image and provide a dark gradient in the bottom. The code is written below

```
package com.example.modifiers

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.modifiers.ui.theme.ModifiersTheme
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.material3.CardDefaults
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.anivesh_photo)
            val description = "This is Anivesh"
            val title = "Anivesh is a student"
            ImageCard(painter = painter, contentDescription = description, title =title )

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ImageCard(
    painter:Painter,
    contentDescription:String,
    title:String,
    modifier:Modifier=Modifier
){
    Card (
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(5.dp)
    ){
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)){
            Image(painter = Painter, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart

            )
            {
                Text(title, style = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 16.sp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I received is written below:

```
"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public fun Image(bitmap: ImageBitmap, contentDescription: String?, modifier: Modifier = ..., alignment: Alignment = ..., contentScale: ContentScale = ..., alpha: Float = ..., colorFilter: ColorFilter? = ..., filterQuality: FilterQuality = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation
public fun Image(painter: Painter, contentDescription: String?, modifier: Modifier = ..., alignment: Alignment = ..., contentScale: ContentScale = ..., alpha: Float = ..., colorFilter: ColorFilter? = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation
public fun Image(imageVector: ImageVector, contentDescription: String?, modifier: Modifier = ..., alignment: Alignment = ..., contentScale: ContentScale = ..., alpha: Float = ..., colorFilter: ColorFilter? = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation
```

This is what I'm was trying to do:

[image]

Comment: I observe a typo in line Image(painter = Painter, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
it should be painter as per the argument name you have defined

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I tried changing it but the error still persists

Comment: You are missing a parameter `contentDescription`, always check for the mandatory parameters in function definition, or the error dialog presented in Android studio

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 things that this code is complaining about and both are in the same line:

```
Image(painter = Painter, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
```

When you're initialising the `Image` there is a mandatory parameter that you need to pass, called `contentDescription` which is of type `String`. You can pass even an empty string for this so it doesn't complain.

Additionally, `painter = Painter` is wrong because the `Painter` object I assume is the one that is passed as an argument to the `ImageCard` composable function up top. In that case you probably have a typo, because the variable names are case-sensitive, meaning the argument name, passed in the function `ImageCard`, is with all lower case.

In order for your code to compile and not complain, you can adjust the line I mentioned above to be something like the following:

```
Image(painter = painter, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, contentDescription = "")
```